# Fetch information about my private npm package via the npm registry REST api

Tags: rest, http, npm, package

We can fetch public package via the npm registry REST api with the following GET:

```
registry.npmjs.org/:package
```

When I try to fetch my private npm package this fails with a 404 error.

How can I fetch information about my private npm package? To install my private npm package I use a token. Do I need to include this token with the api call as well?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I have been looking for documentation on the REST api on how to do this without any luck.

Comment: @GudlaugurEgilsson I'm afraid not. I'm still searching for a way to do this via REST api.

Comment: Figured this out, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging in the npm cli sources, it turns out the answer lies in setting an Authorization header like this:

```
const registryUrl = require('registry-url');
const request = require('superagent');
const url = require('url');

function registryPackage(name, opts, callback) {
    request
        .get(url.resolve(registryUrl(), name))
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${opts.token}`)
        .end(function(err, response) {
            callback(err, response.body)
        })
}
module.exports = registryPackage;
```

Token is the _authToken from .npmrc file after npm login

Comment: Thank you, I will test it in the upcoming week!

Comment: Can you provide a plain GET request (including the a full example URL and an example token)?

Comment: I don't really know what qualifies as a plain GET request. The URL would in this case resolve to something like ```https://registry.npmjs.org/@myorg/mypackage```
 and the token is something like ```637a423b-5f84-41e8-9faf-05321a3ef938```. ```name``` parameter in this case is ```@myorg/mypackage``` and opts is ```{ token:'637a423b-5f84-41e8-9faf-05321a3ef938'}```